# How to use function overloading to implement a bidirectional mapping function?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, overloading

### TL;DR

#### [Try it online](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=type%20Digit%20%3D%20'1'%20%7C%20'2'%0D%0Atype%20Alpha%20%3D%20'a'%20%7C%20'b'%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20hard%20code%20a%20bidirectional%20map%20between%20Digit%20and%20Alpha%0D%0Aconst%20map%3A%20Record%3CDigit%2C%20Alpha%3E%20%26%20Record%3CAlpha%2C%20Digit%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20'1'%3A%20'a'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20'2'%3A%20'b'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20'a'%3A%20'1'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20'b'%3A%20'2'%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20digit%3A%20Digit%20%3D%20'1'%0D%0Alet%20digitArr%3A%20Digit%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5B'1'%2C%20'2'%5D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20alpha%20%3D%20map%5Bdigit%5D%20%2F%2F%20inferred%20type%20of%20alpha%20is%20%60Alpha%60%0D%0Alet%20digit2%20%3D%20map%5Balpha%5D%20%2F%2F%20inferred%20type%20of%20digit2%20is%20%60Digit%60%0D%0Alet%20alphaArr%20%3D%20digitArr.map(d%20%3D%3E%20map%5Bd%5D)%20%2F%2F%20inferred%20type%20of%20alphaArr%20is%20%60Alpha%5B%5D%60%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20hard%20coded%20map%20does%20help%20the%20type%20system%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20mapping(digit%3A%20Digit)%3A%20Alpha%20%7B%20return%20map%5Bdigit%5D%20%7D%0D%0Alet%20alphaArr2%20%3D%20digitArr.map(mapping)%20%2F%2F%20works%2C%20alphaArr2%20is%20Alpha%5B%5D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20overloadedMapping(digit%3A%20Digit)%3A%20Alpha%0D%0Afunction%20overloadedMapping(alpha%3A%20Alpha)%3A%20Digit%0D%0Afunction%20overloadedMapping(key%3A%20Digit%20%7C%20Alpha)%3A%20Digit%20%7C%20Alpha%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20map%5Bkey%5D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20d%20%3D%20overloadedMapping('a')%20%2F%2F%20d%20is%20Digit%0D%0Alet%20a%20%3D%20overloadedMapping('1')%20%2F%2F%20a%20is%20Alpha%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20seems%20overloading%20is%20working%0D%0A%2F%2F%20BUT...%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20arr%20%3D%20alphaArr.map(overloadedMapping)%0D%0Alet%20arr2%20%3D%20digitArr.map(overloadedMapping)%20%2F%2F%20type%20inference%20fails!!%20But%20why%3F%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20It%20seems%20like%20the%20order%20of%20the%20overloading%20definition%20determines%20which%20line%20of%20above%20code%20fails%2C%20but%20I%20don't%20know%20why%20it's%20happening%0D%0A)

---

I have two union types (both string literals) and a hard coded mapping object which maps these two types to each other.

```ts
type Digit = '1' | '2'
type Alpha = 'a' | 'b'
const map: Record<Digit, Alpha> & Record<Alpha, Digit> = {
    '1': 'a',
    '2': 'b',
    'a': '1',
    'b': '2'
}
```

The hard coded map works nice when being used agains singleton values.

```ts
let digit: Digit = '1'
let alpha = map[digit] // alpha is inferred as Alpha
let digit2 = map[alpha] // digit2 is inferred as Digit
```

Wrapping it with a function and then mapping over an array is also possible.

```ts
let digitArr: Digit[] = ['1', '2']
let alphaArr = digitArr.map(d => map[d]) // inferred as Alpha[]
```

But when I want to use only one function, with overloading, to achieve bidirectional mapping, i.e.

```ts
digitArr.map(mapping) // returns Alpha[]
alphaArr.map(mapping) // returns Digit[]
// where digitArr and alphaArr is deterministically typed as Digit[] and Alpha[]
```

the type system complains about it and I don't know how to make it happy.

My function definition:

```ts
function overloadedMapping(digit: Digit): Alpha
function overloadedMapping(alpha: Alpha): Digit
function overloadedMapping(key: Digit | Alpha): Digit | Alpha {
    return map[key]
}
```

This function also works nice with singleton values and fails on one kind of array.

```ts
let d = overloadedMapping('a') // d is of type Digit
let a = overloadedMapping('1') // a is of type Alpha
let arr = alphaArr.map(overloadedMapping) // arr is of type Digit[]. works? why?
let arr2 = digitArr.map(overloadedMapping) // type inference fails!! why?
```

An interesting observation: When the overloading declaration order is switched, the array mapping which fails also alternates.

### [Try it online](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=type%20Digit%20%3D%20'1'%20%7C%20'2'%0D%0Atype%20Alpha%20%3D%20'a'%20%7C%20'b'%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20hard%20code%20a%20bidirectional%20map%20between%20Digit%20and%20Alpha%0D%0Aconst%20map%3A%20Record%3CDigit%2C%20Alpha%3E%20%26%20Record%3CAlpha%2C%20Digit%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20'1'%3A%20'a'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20'2'%3A%20'b'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20'a'%3A%20'1'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20'b'%3A%20'2'%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20digit%3A%20Digit%20%3D%20'1'%0D%0Alet%20digitArr%3A%20Digit%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5B'1'%2C%20'2'%5D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20alpha%20%3D%20map%5Bdigit%5D%20%2F%2F%20inferred%20type%20of%20alpha%20is%20%60Alpha%60%0D%0Alet%20digit2%20%3D%20map%5Balpha%5D%20%2F%2F%20inferred%20type%20of%20digit2%20is%20%60Digit%60%0D%0Alet%20alphaArr%20%3D%20digitArr.map(d%20%3D%3E%20map%5Bd%5D)%20%2F%2F%20inferred%20type%20of%20alphaArr%20is%20%60Alpha%5B%5D%60%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20hard%20coded%20map%20does%20help%20the%20type%20system%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20mapping(digit%3A%20Digit)%3A%20Alpha%20%7B%20return%20map%5Bdigit%5D%20%7D%0D%0Alet%20alphaArr2%20%3D%20digitArr.map(mapping)%20%2F%2F%20works%2C%20alphaArr2%20is%20Alpha%5B%5D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20overloadedMapping(digit%3A%20Digit)%3A%20Alpha%0D%0Afunction%20overloadedMapping(alpha%3A%20Alpha)%3A%20Digit%0D%0Afunction%20overloadedMapping(key%3A%20Digit%20%7C%20Alpha)%3A%20Digit%20%7C%20Alpha%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20map%5Bkey%5D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20d%20%3D%20overloadedMapping('a')%20%2F%2F%20d%20is%20Digit%0D%0Alet%20a%20%3D%20overloadedMapping('1')%20%2F%2F%20a%20is%20Alpha%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20seems%20overloading%20is%20working%0D%0A%2F%2F%20BUT...%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20arr%20%3D%20alphaArr.map(overloadedMapping)%0D%0Alet%20arr2%20%3D%20digitArr.map(overloadedMapping)%20%2F%2F%20type%20inference%20fails!!%20But%20why%3F%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20It%20seems%20like%20the%20order%20of%20the%20overloading%20definition%20determines%20which%20line%20of%20above%20code%20fails%2C%20but%20I%20don't%20know%20why%20it's%20happening%0D%0A)(same as the first link)

Comment: Just a side note: enums are bidirectional maps already built into TypeScript. You can create one (`enum MyMap { Alpha = 0, Beta = 1}`) and access both keys and values (`MyMap['Alpha']`, `MyMap[0]`).

Comment: Hi Karol, thanks.  While `enum` does provide a bidirectional mapping, it doesn't match my needs. Both side of the mapping needs to be arbitrary string literals and a string based enum is not bidirectional mapped. And still, mapping over an array with one function is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When overload resolution fails to match your callback with the desired signature, you can tell TypeScript what your intention is by providing the type parameter explicitly:

```
let arr2 = digitArr.map<Alpha>(overloadedMapping)
```

Now your transformation will be treated as `(value: Digit, index: number, array: Digit[]) => Alpha`.

In this case, opting out of the point-free style will help TypeScript match the overload as well:

```
let arr2 = digitArr.map(digit => overloadedMapping(digit))
```